# Combine Zuhr and Asr when late for Zuhr?

Tags: salat, sunni, salat-qada, shafii, combining-prayers

If I'm late for Zuhr prayer, can I combine it with Asr or must I pray the Zuhr separately from the Asr?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may say **Zuhr and Asr** prayer togather and also **Maghrib and Esha** togather to avoid unnecessary hardship

> Ibn 'Abbas reported:
>
> > "The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) observed the noon and afternoon prayers together, and the sunset and Isha' prayers together without being in a state of fear or in a state of journey." -[Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/59)
>
> The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) did this so that there will be no [unnecessary hardship](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/64).
> <sub>[[Copied From another answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7689/2250)] Courtesy to [Al Ummat مجاهد ♦](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/9/al-ummat)</sub>

The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said:

> "Whoever joins two Prayers together without a legal excuse, he then commits a major sin."
>
> [Source](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vbe/showthread.php?t=6135) [Reported by [At-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/40) and AI-Hakim]  <sub>Note: Sheikh Al Albany graded it as Da'eef Jidaa (ضعيف جدا) i.e very weak.</sub>

You can't say two Salaat together if you don't have a proper reason. It is best to say your prayers in time.

> Imaam Ahmad said that the one who does not pray because of laziness is a kaafir. (Al-Sharh al-Mumti’ ‘ala Zaad al-Mustanqi’, 2/26).[Source](http://www.guidedones.com/metapage/salat/missed_prayer.htm)

Anas ibn Maalik said:

> “The Messenger of Allah(saw) said: ‘If one of you sleeps and misses a prayer, or forgets it, then let him pray it as soon as he remembers, because Allah(swt) says (interpretation of the meaning): ‘… and perform al-salaah for My remembrance.’ [Ta-Ha 20:14]” (Reported by Muslim).
> [Source](http://www.guidedones.com/metapage/salat/missed_prayer.htm)

Delaying the prayer intentionaly:
Many workers delay Zuhr and Asr Prayer till night-time. Quran speaks strictly on guarding our Salat:

> “Guard strictly (five obligatory) As-Salawat (the prayers) especially the middle Salat >(i.e. Asr Prayers)”
>
> [The Holy Quran, 2:238]

There are Fiqh-us-Sunnah about combining two prayers under certain circumstances:

- [Combining the salah at 'Arafa and al-Muzdalifah](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html#2.115b)
- [Combining the salah during traveling](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html#2.115c)
- [Combining two prayers during rain](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html#2.117)
- [Combining the two prayers due to some illness or other excuse](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html#2.118)
- [Combining two prayers due to some pressing need](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html#2.118a)

And many more.... detailed informations:
[Fiqh-us-Sunnah, Volume 2: Combining two prayers](http://www.ymsite.com/books/fiqhussunnah/fus2_37.html)

[Praying on Time is Just as Important](http://www.themodernreligion.com/basic/pray/prayer_timely.htm)

[COMBINING THE TWO PRAYERS](http://www.al-islam.org/masail/1.htm)

Comment: +1 nice answer, but just a **Note**: The first hadith in your answer is inauthentic (very weak in authenticity).

Comment: @AlUmmat: how do you know? So does it mean we can combine two prayers together without any reason?

Comment: @Noah Sheikh Al Albany graded it as Da'eef Jidaa (ضعيف جدا) i.e very weak, or in other words inauthentic (see Jami'i Tirmidhy by Al Albany).  And I do not mean to combine, what I mean is it is ok to like pray prayers together like if you want to pray Dhur and Asr together then you can.

Comment: al-islam.org is a shia website.
As for themodernreligion.com, " its deviant Sufi teachings are not evident in the initial pages."- see video description at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYymaMrcZUA .

Comment: @everyone A Sunnah is a Sunnah. can we omit any Sunnah if it's source is week? What if it's correct? I don't know about you, but I can't risk discarding anything our Prophet (SM.) said as long as it doesn't collide with Al-Qur'an.

Comment: @ImtiazMahbubKhan It is best to discard that which is inauthentic (weak, fabricated etc...) and keep to the authentic Ahadith.  Furthermore the following of any hadith whatever it is whether someone believes it is sunnah or carries sunnah while disregarding it's strength/authenticity (Saheeh, Hasan, etc... ) is not of the sunnah in of itself.  I suggest to check the introduction of Asilsilah Ada'eefah by Al Albany.

Answer (score 7):

You may (it is permissible to) pray Dhur and Asr together even if you are not on travel.  You can also pray Maghrib and Isha' together if you wish even if you are not traveling.

> The Prophet used to make Dhur and asr together, and Maghrib and Isha'
> Together in Madinah when there was no danger, rain, or travel.
>
> [Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/59)

And that is by making Dhuhr and Asr together, making it eight Rak'at, and making Maghrib and Isha' together making it seven Rak'ats, [source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/39).

The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) did this so that there will be no [unnecessary hardship](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/64).

For further reading see [this](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/102505) (it is in Arabic).

Comment: that hadith does not say anything about what prayer it is 7 or 8 rakaats

Comment: @qdinar no prayer is 7 or 8 7 and 8 are the sum of raka'at of the two prayers you are combining/joining

Comment: @Medi1Saif i mean, it can be about nafil prayer.

Comment: @qdinar no it clearly isn't, based on the clear text of the hadith the speech is only about the fard prayers.

Comment: @Medi1Saif "The Prophet (ﷺ) prayed seven rak'at together and eight rak`at together." - where? but i have found a text above arabic text where seems Gata says that it is about magrib and isha.

Answer (score 3):

Combining Zuhr Asr doesn't mean that you pray 8 rakaat together in one go but it means that we finish 4 rakaat Zuhr first then we start 4 rakaat of Asr.

Muslims also combine the prayers on Hajj.

It is a relaxation given by the islam and prophet p.b.u.h. so why not avail it.

Answer (score 0):

i think,

if you mean that you are out of the time of zuhr, then you cannot combine them, you should make kaza of zuhr.

if you meant that you are just close to end of zuhr time but inside of it, then, i tend to think that you can pray zuhr, than wait for beginning of asr, and pray asr, and it is named combining of prayers , as far as i know.

Answer (score -1):

I was taught that the prophet (saw) would pray Thur at its latis, or before the shadows become double lighth,and then would get up and pray the asr right behind it,so right before Thur go's out and asr is coming in,so there would be a pause in-between, this is the understand I got,how can you pray asr salat if its not in,and ALLAH knows best!