# Is one who does not pray out of laziness a Kafir?

Tags: salat, source-identification

In [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7695/9), it provides an opinion of Imam Ahmad:

> Imaam Ahmad said that the one who does not pray because of laziness is
>   a kaafir. (Al-Sharh al-Mumti’ ‘ala Zaad al-Mustanqi’, 2/26)

I am wondering, is there any authentic Hadith that support this opinion of his? What did the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) about the consequence of missing salat without an excuse? would one become disbeliever?

***Authentic Sources Please***

Comment: You can download the volume in question [here](http://www.archive.org/download/waq53629/02_53630.pdf) and check page 26. On a cursory reading I found no primary evidence but I didn't have time to check the following pages for a deeper discussion.

Comment: Salat is one of the Pillars of Islam. Though there are conflicting opinions on whether supporting the Pillars of Islam is a requirement for being Muslim.

Answer (score 3):

The most basic and simple answer they used to conclude this rule is the hadith in **Sahih Muslim** :

> Jabir (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said, "Between a man and disbelief and paganism is the abandonment of Salat (prayer)."

[Muslim].

---

Now, Here are more Hadiths that Imam Ahmed and others used to support their opinion :

> Buraidah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said, "That which differentiates us from the disbelievers and hypocrites is our performance of Salat. He who abandons it, becomes a disbeliever."

[At-Tirmidhi].

> It has been narrated on the authority of 'Auf b. Malik that the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) said: The best of your rulers are those whom you love and who love you, who invoke God's blessings upon you and you invoke His blessings upon them. And the worst of your rulers are those whom you hate and who hate you and whom you curse and who curse you. It was asked (by those present): Shouldn't we overthrow them with the help of the sword? He said: No, as long as they establish prayer among you. If you then find anything detestable in them. You should hate their administration, but do not withdraw yourselves from their obedience.

[Muslim]

---

There are verses in the Quran too. But since you are looking for Hadiths only then I will not post them in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Allah, the most merciful says: [narrated]

> "...So woe unto those performers of salah (prayers)(hypocrites), Those who delay their salah (prayer from their stated fixed times)...."
>   (Quran, chapter 107, verses 4-5) [Verse 4](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=107&verse=4)-->[Verse 5](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=107&verse=5)

### Translations of verse 5:

> Sahih International: [But] who are heedless of their prayer -
>
> Pickthall: Who are heedless of their prayer;
>
> Yusuf Ali: Who are neglectful of their prayers,
>
> Shakir: Who are unmindful of their prayers,
>
> Muhammad Sarwar: who become confused during their prayers,
>
> Mohsin Khan: Who delay their Salat (prayer) from their stated fixed times,
>
> Arberry: and are heedless of their prayers,

*[Since there are controversies about delayed prayer, I prefer to say it within time.
Allah knows best. I can't risk being sinful and delay intentionally.]*

Comment: I read a hadith like this: "Allah throws off the salaat that was delayed intentionally"
I didn't find any source of this hadith on the internet. Since it's a hadith, I can't disobey it and at the same time, I can't be sure of it since I don't have any authentic resource currently. I'll try to find it out as soon as possible.