# Are you supposed to delay your salah until the bleeding stops? (Sunni view)

Tags: quran, hadith, salat

I understand that bleeding breaks the rules of purity and nullifies Wudhu– which means you cannot make salat. But are you supposed to delay your salat until the bleeding stops?

Sunni view please with references from Quran, Hadith, and/or fatwa.

Comment: Can I post fatwa from http://www.islamweb.net and other reliable sources here? Because there is no Hadith/Sunnah directly indicating this situation.

Comment: @ImtiazMahbubKhan, please do!

Comment: I think what you mean is *bleeding*. *Blood* is *blood* and if it doesn't spill, nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

In response to a similar **[question](http://www.islamicboard.com/prayer/134307556-bleeding-while-doing-wudu.html)**, Sheikh Ahmad Kutty, a senior lecturer and an Islamic scholar at the Islamic Institute of Toronto, Ontario, Canada, states:

> > "Bleeding from any of the natural orifices (anus, urethra or vagina) definitely breaks one's wudu'.
> >
> > Bleeding from a cut or wound, however, does not break one's wudu'.
>
> This is supported by strong evidence in the primary sources of Islam
>   and is endorsed by the Salaf (the pious predecessors). It is common
>   knowledge that the Companions used to pray while they were bleeding
>   from their wounds. `Caliph Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) prayed
>   while bleeding from stab wounds.` The above rule also applies to blood
>   taken for medical tests."

**Hazrat Ali (may ALLAH be pleased with him) said that:**

> If you are drowning in water and if you remember that it is time for Prayer(Namaz), then yours Intention should be to offer Salah(Prayer).

.

> “The Muslims used to keep on praying while wounded.” (Bukhari). [Source](http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?216489-Bleeding-and-time-for-Salat)

From http://www.islam-qa.com/en/ref/2176/bleeding:

> We know of no evidence (daleel) to indicate that bleeding from any part of the body other than the vagina invalidates one’s wudoo’. The basic principle is that it does not break wudoo’. Acts of worship should be based on sound reports, so no one is permitted to say that any act of worship is prescribed by Islam unless he has evidence.
>
> Some scholars suggested that wudoo’ is broken if the amount of blood lost from any place other than the vagina is considered to be excessive.
>
> **If a person in this condition does wudoo’ in order to be on the safe side, then this is good, because the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:**
>
> > “Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you doubt.” (Reported by al-Nisaa’i, 8/328; al-Tirmidhi, 7/221 Tuhfat al-Ahwadhi; al-Haakim, 2/13, 4/99)

Therefore your main concern should be to stop the bleeding as best as you could and say the prayer within the fixed time of that salaat. Do what you think Allah would like the most. Allah knows best. He is the one to accept your prayer.

About the delay to say prayer, see this question-answer: [Combine Zuhr and Asr when late for Zuhr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/)