# When/why is it okay to combine prayers?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, combining-prayers

I have read that some groups combine prayers at different prayer times. This has been confusing me, because I don't understand the reasoning behind this. (I am a new Muslim.)

- When is it okay to combine prayers?
- Which prayers can be combined?
- Why it is OK to combine prayers?

Comment: See this: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/combine-zuhr-and-asr-when-late-for-zuhr

Answer (score 1):

Daily prayers are timely obligations ([4:103](http://quran.com/4/103)). You just cannot postpone them. In 4:103, we are being told to observe prayer even in a time of fear/anxiety. If you miss it, you simply miss it. You cannot delay, subtract, or add them together. You lived today for once, right? Can you delay today and live it tomorrow? Can you combine your heartbeats and breaths with those of tomorrow?