# Is there evidence that combining prayers is not permissible without hardship?

Tags: salat, hadith, shia-sunni

There is an authentic hadith which says:

> The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) observed the noon and afternoon prayers together, and the sunset and Isha' prayers together without being in a state of fear or in a state of journey.
>   <sub>[Sahih Muslim 705 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/59)</sub>

Yet despite this text, there are some who say combining the prayers in such a way unless there is a pressing hardship is not permissible.

Does anyone know the evidence for such a position? It would seem from the hadith that combining is permissible as long as there is a valid reason for it (such as you are working during the day or in school and cannot take time off till you reach home at 'Asr time).

Also a related question, is combining the prayers in such a way (Zurh with Asr and Maghrib with Isha, 4 and 4, 4 and 3) what the Shia do and is their evidence the same as this hadith?

I think this is a different question than [Combine Zuhr and Asr when late for Zuhr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7686/17163), because none of the answers there provide an evidence for saying combining is not permissible (there is only one hadith quoted which is very weak).

Comment: "Indeed, as‑Salaah is enjoined on the believers at fixed times" [al-Nisa’ 4:103]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Zuhr and Asr when late for Zuhr?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/combine-zuhr-and-asr-when-late-for-zuhr)

Comment: There are all references you need in the above question you also added link to in your post.

Comment: Who are the people who say combining prayers is impermissible without hardship?  Why not ask them for their evidence?